# noise synthesis arbitrary PSD

Tags: noise, power-spectral-density, signal-synthesis

I have noise measurements for a circuit, in units of noise power (measured in Watts against a known load), per frequency bin.
For simulation purposes, I wish to synthesize noise with the same spectral shape.

I believe I can model my noise as Gaussian, but it isn't white.
How can I synthesize such noise?

My guess is that I can synthesize WGN using MATLAB's `wgn` function, and then filter it. However, I'm not sure how to create the filter. Additionally, my signal is single ended so I guess I should add some offset to account for it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Producing Colored Noise from a given PSD Data](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/6250/producing-colored-noise-from-a-given-psd-data)

Comment: (this was literally the top question recommended to me as I typed in your question title in the "new question" page)

Comment: Some good options here: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/322/41790.